# Error after installing Matlab integration for Jupyter

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to integrate MATLAB into Jupyter to use markdown features in Jupyter notebooks. I've follow this guide on github for the proxy installation to Anaconda environment: https://github.com/mathworks/jupyter-matlab-proxy#matlab-kernel-create-a-jupyter-notebook-using-matlab-kernel-for-jupyter

The installation appears OK and I can start a MATLAB kernel. However, I can't execute any commands with a message saying: `Error connecting to MATLAB. Check the status of MATLAB by clicking the "Open MATLAB" button. Retry after ensuring MATLAB is running successfully` as seen below.

The problem is I don't see such "Open MATLAB" button on the kernel. I've tried restarting both Anaconda and the computer but it doesn't work. Is there a solution for this issue?

[image]